# C++ Error when using Bullet Physics and Texture

Tags: c++, glfw, glew, bulletphysics

**TextureLoader: fileName /root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Textures/globe.jpg
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)**

when I try to run this:

```
// GLEW needs to be included first
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW is included next
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "ShaderLoader.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "LightRenderer.h"

#include "MeshRenderer.h"
#include "TextureLoader.h"

#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
#include<chrono>
#include "TextRenderer.h"

TextRenderer* label;

void initGame();
void renderScene(float dt);
void addRigidBodies();
void myTickCallback(btDynamicsWorld *dynamicsWorld, btScalar timeStep);

Camera* camera;
LightRenderer* light;

MeshRenderer* sphere;
MeshRenderer* ground;
MeshRenderer* enemy;

//physics
btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld;

GLuint flatShaderProgram, litTexturedShaderProgram, textProgram;

GLuint texturedShaderProgram;

GLuint sphereTexture, groundTexture;

bool grounded = false;

bool gameover = true;
int score = 0;


void initGame() {
    
    // Enable the depth testing
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    ShaderLoader shader;
    flatShaderProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/FlatModel.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/FlatModel.fs");
    texturedShaderProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/TexturedModel.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/TexturedModel.fs");
    litTexturedShaderProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/LitTexturedModel.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/LitTexturedModel.fs");
    textProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/text.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/CollisionLoopsLighting/text.fs");
    TextureLoader tLoader;
    
    sphereTexture = tLoader.getTextureID("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Textures/globe.jpg");
    groundTexture = tLoader.getTextureID("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Textures/ground.jpg");
    
    camera = new Camera(45.0f, 800, 600, 0.1f, 100.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 4.0f, 20.0f));

    light = new LightRenderer(MeshType::kSphere, camera);
    light->setProgram(flatShaderProgram);
    light->setPosition(glm::vec3(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f));
    light->setColor(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    //text label
    label = new TextRenderer("Score: 0", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/fonts/gooddog.ttf", 64, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), textProgram);
    label->setPosition(glm::vec2(320.0f, 500.0f));

    //init physics

    btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
    btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
    btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();

    dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
    dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -9.8f, 0));

    dynamicsWorld->setInternalTickCallback(myTickCallback);
    
    addRigidBodies();
}


void myTickCallback(btDynamicsWorld *dynamicsWorld, btScalar timeStep) {

    if (!gameover) {
        // Get enemy transform
        btTransform t(enemy->rigidBody->getWorldTransform());
        // Set enemy position
        t.setOrigin(t.getOrigin() + btVector3(-15, 0, 0) * timeStep);
        // Check if offScreen
        if (t.getOrigin().x() <= -18.0f) {
            t.setOrigin(btVector3(18, 1, 0));
            score++;
            label->setText("Score: " + std::to_string(score));
        }
        enemy->rigidBody->setWorldTransform(t);
        enemy->rigidBody->getMotionState()->setWorldTransform(t);
    }
    // Check Collisions
    grounded = false;
    int numManifolds = dynamicsWorld->getDispatcher()->getNumManifolds();
    for (int i = 0; i < numManifolds; i++) {
        btPersistentManifold *contactManifold = dynamicsWorld->getDispatcher()->getManifoldByIndexInternal(i);
        int numContacts = contactManifold->getNumContacts();
        if (numContacts > 0) {
            const btCollisionObject *objA = contactManifold->getBody0();
            const btCollisionObject *objB = contactManifold->getBody1();

            MeshRenderer* gModA = (MeshRenderer*)objA->getUserPointer();
            MeshRenderer* gModB = (MeshRenderer*)objB->getUserPointer();

                if ((gModA->name == "hero" && gModB->name == "enemy") ||
                    (gModA->name == "enemy" && gModB->name == "hero")) {

                    //printf("collision: %s with %s \n", gModA->name, gModB->name);
                    if (gModB->name == "enemy") {
                        btTransform b(gModB->rigidBody->getWorldTransform());
                        b.setOrigin(btVector3(18, 1, 0));
                        gModB->rigidBody->setWorldTransform(b);
                        gModB->rigidBody->getMotionState()->setWorldTransform(b);
                    }else {
                    
                        btTransform a(gModA->rigidBody->getWorldTransform());
                        a.setOrigin(btVector3(18, 1, 0));
                        gModA->rigidBody->setWorldTransform(a);
                        gModA->rigidBody->getMotionState()->setWorldTransform(a);
                    }
                    gameover = true;
                    score = 0;
                    label->setText("Score: " + std::to_string(score));
                }
                if ((gModA->name == "hero" && gModB->name == "ground") ||
                    (gModA->name == "ground" && gModB->name == "hero")) {

                    //printf("collision: %s with %s \n", gModA->name, gModB->name);
                    grounded = true;
                }
        }
    }
}

void renderScene(float dt){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    // Draw Objects
    light->draw();
    sphere->draw();
    enemy->draw();
    ground->draw();

    //debugDraw->SetMatrices(bulletDebugProgram, camera->getViewMatrix(), camera->getprojectionMatrix());
    //dynamicsWorld->debugDrawWorld();
    label->draw();
}

void updateKeyboard(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods){
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); 
    }
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        if (gameover) {
            gameover = false;
        } else {
            if (grounded == true) {
                grounded = false;
                sphere->rigidBody->applyImpulse(btVector3(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f), btVector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
                printf("pressed up key \n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, " Hello OpenGL ", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, updateKeyboard);
    glewInit();
    initGame();
    auto previousTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        float dt = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - previousTime).count();

        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(dt);

        renderScene(dt);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        previousTime = currentTime;
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    delete camera;
    delete light;

    return 0;
}

void addRigidBodies() {
    // Sphere Rigid Body
    btCollisionShape* sphereShape = new btSphereShape(1);
    btDefaultMotionState* sphereMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, 0.5, 0)));

    btScalar mass = 13.0f;
    btVector3 sphereInertia(0, 0, 0);
    sphereShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, sphereInertia);

    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo sphereRigidBodyCI(mass, sphereMotionState, sphereShape, sphereInertia);
    btRigidBody* sphereRigidBody = new btRigidBody(sphereRigidBodyCI);

    sphereRigidBody->setFriction(1.0f);
    sphereRigidBody->setRestitution(0.0f);

    sphereRigidBody->setActivationState(DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(sphereRigidBody);

    // Sphere Mesh
    sphere = new MeshRenderer(MeshType::kSphere, "hero", camera, sphereRigidBody, light, 0.1f, 0.5f);
    sphere->setProgram(litTexturedShaderProgram);
    sphere->setTexture(sphereTexture);
    sphere->setScale(glm::vec3(1.0f));

    sphereRigidBody->setUserPointer(sphere);

    // Ground Rigid body

    btCollisionShape* groundShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(4.0f, 0.5f, 4.0f));
    btDefaultMotionState* groundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, -1.0f, 0)));

    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo groundRigidBodyCI(0.0f, groundMotionState, groundShape, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
    btRigidBody* groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);

    groundRigidBody->setFriction(1.0);
    groundRigidBody->setRestitution(0.0);
    groundRigidBody->setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject::CF_STATIC_OBJECT);

    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);

    // Ground Mesh
    ground = new MeshRenderer(MeshType::kCube, "ground", camera, groundRigidBody, light, 0.1f, 0.5f);
    ground->setProgram(litTexturedShaderProgram);
    ground->setTexture(groundTexture);
    ground->setScale(glm::vec3(4.0f, 0.5f, 4.0f));

    groundRigidBody->setUserPointer(ground);

    // Enemy Rigid body

    btCollisionShape* shape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    btDefaultMotionState* motionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
        btVector3(18.0, 1.0f, 0)));
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rbCI(0.0f, motionState, shape, btVector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    btRigidBody* rb = new btRigidBody(rbCI);

    rb->setFriction(1.0);
    rb->setRestitution(0.0);
    //rb->setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject::CF_KINEMATIC_OBJECT);
    rb->setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject::CF_NO_CONTACT_RESPONSE);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(rb);

    // Enemy Mesh
    enemy = new MeshRenderer(MeshType::kCube, "enemy", camera, rb, light, 0.1f, 0.5f);
    enemy->setProgram(litTexturedShaderProgram);
    enemy->setTexture(groundTexture);
    enemy->setScale(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    rb->setUserPointer(enemy);
}
```

I am able to compile it successfully. But cannot run the executable file due to **malloc() error**.

The working one is:

```
// GLEW needs to be included first
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW is included next
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "ShaderLoader.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include "LightRenderer.h"

#include "MeshRenderer.h"
#include "TextureLoader.h"

#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>

#include<chrono>


void initGame();
void renderScene();


Camera* camera;
LightRenderer* light;

MeshRenderer* sphere;
MeshRenderer* ground;

//physics
btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld;

void initGame() {
    
    // Enable the depth testing
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    
    ShaderLoader shader;

    GLuint flatShaderProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/FlatModel.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/FlatModel.fs");
    GLuint texturedShaderProgram = shader.createProgram("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/TexturedModel.vs", "/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Shaders/TexturedModel.fs");

    camera = new Camera(45.0f, 800, 600, 0.1f, 100.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 4.0f, 20.0f));

    light = new LightRenderer(MeshType::kTriangle, camera);
    light->setProgram(flatShaderProgram);
    light->setPosition(glm::vec3(0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f));

    TextureLoader tLoader;

    GLuint sphereTexture = tLoader.getTextureID("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Textures/globe.jpg");
    GLuint groundTexture = tLoader.getTextureID("/root/SourceCodes/CPP/Assets/Textures/ground.jpg");

    //init physics
    btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();
    btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
    btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();

    dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);
    dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -9.8f, 0));
    
    // Sphere Rigid Body

    btCollisionShape* sphereShape = new btSphereShape(1);
    btDefaultMotionState* sphereMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, 10, 0)));

    btScalar mass = 10.0;
    btVector3 sphereInertia(0, 0, 0);
    sphereShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, sphereInertia);

    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo sphereRigidBodyCI(mass, sphereMotionState, sphereShape, sphereInertia);

    btRigidBody* sphereRigidBody = new btRigidBody(sphereRigidBodyCI);
    sphereRigidBody->setRestitution(1.0f);
    sphereRigidBody->setFriction(1.0f);

    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(sphereRigidBody);
    
    // Sphere Mesh

    sphere = new MeshRenderer(MeshType::kSphere, camera, sphereRigidBody);
    sphere->setProgram(texturedShaderProgram);
    sphere->setTexture(sphereTexture);
    sphere->setScale(glm::vec3(1.0f));

    // Ground Rigid body

    btCollisionShape* groundShape = new btBoxShape(btVector3(4.0f, 0.5f, 4.0f));
    btDefaultMotionState* groundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, -2.0f, 0)));

    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo groundRigidBodyCI(0.0f, new btDefaultMotionState(), groundShape, btVector3(0, 0, 0));

    btRigidBody* groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);

    groundRigidBody->setFriction(1.0);
    groundRigidBody->setRestitution(0.9);

    groundRigidBody->setCollisionFlags(btCollisionObject::CF_STATIC_OBJECT);

    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);


    // Ground Mesh
    ground = new MeshRenderer(MeshType::kCube, camera, groundRigidBody);
    ground->setProgram(texturedShaderProgram);
    ground->setTexture(groundTexture);
    ground->setScale(glm::vec3(4.0f, 0.5f, 4.0f));
}


void renderScene(){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    //light->draw();

    sphere->draw();
    
    ground->draw();


}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, " Hello OpenGL ", NULL, NULL);
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    initGame();

    auto previousTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        float dt = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - previousTime).count();

        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(dt);

        renderScene();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        previousTime = currentTime;
    }

    glfwTerminate();


    delete camera;
    delete light;

    return 0;
}
```

There are few cpp files:
main.cpp Mesh.cpp LightRenderer.cpp TextRenderer.cpp MeshRenderer.cpp ShaderLoader.cpp TextureLoader.cpp Camera.cpp

But I don't think the problem is in another cpp files, since the running one is working nicely. The only differences are I add enemy loops and text rendering.

How to fix this?

This is the link to obtain the full codes:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/CPP-Game-Development-By-Example/tree/master/Chapter08/8.OpenGLProject

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for: it runs your program, one line at a time, and [shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)!! This is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: I don't use debugger, I compile it with terminal / xterm directly not using IDE. Should I use `-Wall` at the end of compiling? @SamVarshavchik I just recently learn CPP this week.

Comment: I see the real problem here. Here's the right way to learn C++: Step 1: spend 3-5 years learning core C++ fundamental concepts, which includes learning how to use debuggers, as well as core C++ topics like classes, templates, containers, iterators, algorithms, and many others. Step 2: after acquiring above average C++ knowledge and experience, then it's time branch out and learn boutique, specialized technologies and domains, like like OpenGL and GLFW. Every attempt to skip the first step will always end in tears.

Comment: Alright, then I will learn step 1 first, takes years, but time worth spend learning C++, science and engineering too. Thanks.